# Positive and negative number difference

Tags: functions

I'm trying to find out an equation to be able to know if the number difference is positive, negative or zero

What I have right now is

```
f(x,y) = ((x-y)/abs(x-y))
```

it works if there is the difference but if the numbers, but numbers cannot be the same, because of the division by zero.

any idea?

This is expected result

```
| x    | y    | f(x,y) |
|------|------|--------|
| 2500 | 2500 | 0      |
| 3000 | 2500 | 1      |
| 2000 | 2500 | -1     |
```

Comment: Just define $f(x,y)=0$ whenever $x=y$. You may also want to check the sign function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function)

Answer (score 0):

What about
$$f(x,y)=\left\lfloor\sqrt[3]{x-y\over |x-y|+1}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\sqrt[3]{y-x\over |x-y|+1}\right\rfloor$$?